# Adb.exe file auto deleted from platform-tools

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk, platform-tools

Adb.exe auto deleted from platform-tools , i have no antivirus installed on my pc. I disable windows defender and firewall also. but still it auto deleted by someone ...!what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Try to clean your system using some anti virus this problem may occurs due to some virus in your System.